# What's the correct date format to turn this string into a date?

Tags: cocoa, nsdateformatter

I'm consuming a JSON API, which returns dates, such as the following: `2012-11-13T17:32Z`. What's the correct value for a `formatString` for an associated `NSDateFormatter` instance?

Edit:

I tried `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh':'mm'Z'"`.

Comment: This looks like an RFC date format... http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt I don't have much experience with ObjC but I would imagine there to be a RFC date formatting utility...

Comment: It is indeed an RFC date. Interesting point about the utility. If you're talking about a Mac utility for generating formatting strings from date strings, there's none that I know of. Not a bad idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the quotes around the colon, and you should be using capital H's for the hours.